# I'm trying to run my JMeter script but it is not executing as expected

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

Basically our test scenario is about adding a party, so whenever we execute the script, every time it should be able to add a new party. But we are unable to see any party created apart from the one that was created while recording the script. I believe this can probably be a issue of some dynamic value but unable to identify it. We used a reg exp for view states already, And session Id is getting generated in the cookie, so do we need to manage anything for that too.

Comment: Please edit this question to explain what you are trying to do. Are you trying to create one party for each 10 users or 1 party for each user? Is your script returning successful but the parties are not created? Or is it returning successful but you can't tell what is happening? We do not have enough information to help you.

Comment: Have a look here: [asking](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/asking). You likely get down votes for [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and [no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Answer (score 1):

As per [4 Things You Should Never Do with Your JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-never-do-your-jmeter-script) guide:

> **Don’t run the script exactly as you recorded it**
>
> After recording your script, there is still some work to do before you run it. It’s necessary to correlate variables, parameterize and add elements, to faithfully simulate users.

So make sure you:

- add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
- correlate all dynamic parameters using relevant [JMeter Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
- inspect all request and especially response details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener - it might be the case your application returns response indicating what went wrong. If not - just make sure JMeter sends the same requests as browser does (apart from dynamic parameters)
- JMeter automatically considers [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, it doesn't do any extra checks so if you want JMeter to automatically fail requests which did not generate "parties" - consider adding i.e. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to them and define pass/fail criteria.